# extract some numbers start with specific number from identity code

Tags: r

I want to identy birth year from identity codes, e.g.:

```
test <- c("1234195212345600", "123419531234561","1234195412345689878")
```

and the expected result is to extract four numbers that start with 19. The final result looks like:

```
test_results <- c("1952", "1953", "1954").
```

I tried:

```
str_extract(test, "19[0-9][0-9]")
```

and it gives

```
NA NA NA
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. What version of R and `stringr()` are you using?

Comment: R4.2.2 do you have other solutions with regular expression?

Comment: @zephryl in my case, it only gives NA, not sure the reason. I want to search for some alternatives.

Comment: Try: `str_extract(test, "19\\d\\d")` and be sure that test is test. Maybe restart R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regmatches` together with `regexpr` or `gregexpr`. The latter is useful for disambiguities.

```
regmatches(test, regexpr('19\\d{2}', test))
# [1] "1952" "1953" "1954" "1919"

regmatches(test, gregexpr('19\\d{2}', test))
# [[1]]
# [1] "1952"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1953"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "1954"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "1919" "1952"
# 
# [[5]]
# character(0)
```

---

*Data:*

```
test <- c("1234195212345600", "123419531234561","1234195412345689878", "19191952", "12121212")
```